# Why can I manually iterate this JSON Data but I'm getting errors when I try to do the same thing with a for loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

New to asyncio, using it to try to make a very large number of API requests more quickly and store the data returned from each request in a dict.  I think I've got the syntax of using asyncio and aiohttp figured out mostly, because I'm getting the data returned but I'm having a hard time taking that data and storing it in a dict.

```
search_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

stats = {"Date":[],"Instance ID":[],"Result":[],"Display Name":[]}


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for search_id in search_ids:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_data(session, search_id))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                      
        for y in responses['entries']:
            stats['Display Name'].append(y['player']['UserInfo']['displayName'])


async def get_data(session, search_id):
    url = f'https://www.myapi.com/{search_id}'

    async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS, ssl=False) as response:
        results = await response.json()
        
        return results['Response']

asyncio.run(main())
```

So when I run this, I get an error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Which makes it seem to me as if the data that has been returned isn't iterable.  However, I've looked at what's being returned and it's exactly what I'm expecting it to be.  So much that if I change the code to look like this instead, it works fine:

```
search_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

stats = {"Date":[],"Instance ID":[],"Result":[],"Display Name":[]}


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for search_id in search_ids:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_data(session, search_id))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                      
        for y in responses:
            stats['Display Name'].append(y['entries'][0]['player']['UserInfo']['displayName'])
            stats['Display Name'].append(y['entries'][1]['player']['UserInfo']['displayName'])
            stats['Display Name'].append(y['entries'][2]['player']['UserInfo']['displayName'])
            stats['Display Name'].append(y['entries'][3]['player']['UserInfo']['displayName'])
            stats['Display Name'].append(y['entries'][4]['player']['UserInfo']['displayName'])
            stats['Display Name'].append(y['entries'][5]['player']['UserInfo']['displayName'])


async def get_data(session, search_id):
    url = f'https://www.myapi.com/{search_id}'

    async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS, ssl=False) as response:
        results = await response.json()
        
        return results['Response']

asyncio.run(main())
```

Am I not basically doing the same thing manually here that I'm trying to do with a For loop on the top snippet?  I would just go with this workaround except that I plan on pulling out much more data from each of these responses and it's not practical to manually do this over and over.

Plus obviously this makes me question if I'm understanding async correctly or not if this is giving me such a simple error.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: "Plus obviously this makes me question if I'm understanding async correctly or not if this is giving me such a simple error." Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you want to know whether the problem has anything to do with whether you understand async correctly, then you should start by *trying to write the code without async*. In this case, you would find that you still have the problem, because the difficulty is with how you understand the data structure. Similarly, you don't need the web connection code to cause the problem, just hard-coded data.

Comment: I've had this code working without async, it's only now trying to move the same code to async that the JSON seems to be parsing differently and it's very unclear why.  I've searched many other places for answers to this before coming here to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You’re iterating over two different things. In the first one you iterate over `responses[“entries”]`. In the second you use `responses`. `responses` is a list (of dictionaries), not a dictionary, so it can only be accessed by index, not by key.

When you ran your code synchronously, all you had to do was iterate over the entries in the response. Now that you're working with multiple responses in a list, you need to iterate over both the responses and the entries in each. To do this, you need to use two separate for loops.

```
responses = await asyncio.gather(
    *[get_data(session, search_id) for search_id in search_ids]
)

for response in responses:
    for entry in response["entries"]:
        stats["Display Name"].append(
            entry["player"]["UserInfo"]["displayName"]
        )
```

Comment: I follow what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to access by Index.  There are several other suggestions here that mention a similar process but are not working for me.  The JSON structure was never a problem for me to parse when I was doing this the other (synched), but struggling to get the same results now that the responses are coming back async, which is the main problem I guess.

Comment: @terribleatthis I added some code to show how to iterate over both things.

Answer (score 0):

the error is because of the key in data type. Please try this code based on your 2nd code

```
search_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

stats = {"Date":[],"Instance ID":[],"Result":[],"Display Name":[]}


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for search_id in search_ids:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_data(session, search_id))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(
                    *[get_data(session, search_id) for search_id in search_ids])
                      
        for response in responses:
            for entry in response["entries"]:
                stats["Display Name"].append(
                     entry["player"]["UserInfo"]["displayName"]
                     )


async def get_data(session, carnage_id):
    url = f'https://www.myapi.com/{search_id}'

    async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS, ssl=False) as response:
        results = await response.json()
        
        return results['Response']

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried this and now I'm receiving the following error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Hi I have updated the the for loop with nested forloop. It would really helpful if you could share the whole data structure of the response variable. **print (responses)**

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
for index, y in enumerate(responses['entries']):
    stats['Display Name'].append(y['entries'][index]['player']['UserInfo']['displayName'])
```